# Sample Size Calculation for intervention designed to decrease time to event outcome

Tags: sample-size

I've been asked to provide a sample size estimate for a RCT of an intervention designed to reduce a waiting time. The investigator believes a reduction of 30 minutes would be important.

As expected, the untransformed times have a long right tail. A log transformation, ln(wait_minutes) appears bimodal.

How should I best approach determining a sample size for this trial?

A sample of historical waiting times (in minutes) is pasted below:

wait_minutes <- c(194, 37, 236, 248, 49, 367, 27, 271, 166, 433, 157, 91, 85, 
129, 37, 150, 119, 324, 254, 166, 116, 166, 34, 187, 78, 150, 
156, 42, 247, 43, 42, 215, 35, 180, 253, 58, 179, 115, 183, 69, 
176, 115, 118, 58, 420, 100, 101, 140, 280, 47, 34, 217, 90, 
134, 225, 121, 138)

Answer (score 1):

Your sample-count isn't incredibly big, so in this case I prefer qqnorm over histogram because bin-size isn't as much of an issue

```
library(extRemes)
qqnorm(wait_minutes)
grid()
abline(mean(wait_minutes),sd(wait_minutes))
c(median(wait_minutes),IQR(wait_minutes)/1.35)
```

The pseudo-sigma for your wait-time is 85.9 minutes.

I would use resampling to get a decent estimate of how the variation in the mean changes with sample size.

Code:

```
elts <- 1:50 #sweep of potential sample sizes
m <- 1000 #number of times to gather data, just makes for clean estimates
sig <- vector(length = length(elts)) #must pre-declare arrays

for (n in elts){  #outer loop

     mu <- numeric()  #reset mu for each element-size
     y <- numeric()   #reset y for each element-size

     for (j in 1:m){

          #draw n elements
          y <- sample(wait_minutes,n,replace=TRUE)

          #compute the mean
          mu[j] <- mean(y)
     }

     #compute variation in your bag of mean estimates and store
     sig[n] <- sd(mu)
}

#plot
plot(elts,sig)
grid()
```

So I use the demo version of [Eureqa](http://www.nutonian.com/download/) and the expression for the standard deviation in the mean given samples is:

$$ \sigma = \frac {95.4}{\sqrt{N}} $$

A plot of the data and fit looks like the following:
[image]

Given that is the standard deviation, and given the idea of 3-sigma control, I personally suggest at least 100 samples to assure that the 3-sigma variation in the mean is less than the size of the main effect.  Given that you only had 57 samples, this may be expensive or uncomfortable.  I think that if you use less than that it is highly risky.  I would prefer to use substantially more than that, and consider the 100 samples the "edge of the cliff" below which the results are in the noise.

Let me think about this and get back to you...